# Move items based on multiple values of SenderName

Tags: vba, outlook

I move email from my inbox to the test folder.

How do I add more sender names?

Instead of moving just 'ABC Sprockets', move 'DFG Widgets' and 'XYZ Zippers' as well in one script.

```
Sub MoveItems()
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Object

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("test")
    Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = 'ABC Sprockets'")
    While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
        myItem.Move myDestFolder
        Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it because I don't have Outlook on my home computer but I recommend looping through an Array of Strings that contains your search terms:

```
Sub MoveItems()
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Object

    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("test")
    Dim varSearchTerm As Variant: For Each varSearchTerm In Array("ABC Sprockets", "DFG Widgets", "XYZ Zippers")
    Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = '" & varSearchTerm & "'")
        While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
            myItem.Move myDestFolder
            Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
        Wend
    Next
End Sub
```

You may also move the enumeration of your search terms like this:

```
Dim varSearchTerms As Variant: varSearchTerms = Array("ABC Sprockets", "DFG Widgets", "XYZ Zippers")
' ...
Dim varSearchTerm As Variant: For Each varSearchTerm In varSearchTerms
Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = '" & varSearchTerm & "'")
' ...
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify every condition in the search string explicitly:

```
Set myItem = myItems.Find("[SenderName] = 'ABC Sprockets' OR [SenderName] = 'DFG Widgets' OR [SenderName] = 'XYZ Zippers'")
```